# puzzled with how actions are being dispatched in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have beeb using redux thing where we pass mapDispatchToProps and dispatch actions inside it .This was the pattern that I was following in most of my react-redux web apps .
I came across this codebase where the developer did something like this.
I am listing all the essential parts of the code.

```
import { fetchSportsFanDetails } from "./actions";
class Profile extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.sportsFanDetails) {
      this.props.fetchSportsFanDetails();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, sportsFanDetails } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.rootStyle}>
        // some code
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => ({
  sportsFanDetails: user.sportsFanDetails,
  isFetchingSportsFanDetails: user.isFetchingSportsFanDetails
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchSportsFanDetails, logoutUser }
)(withStyles(styles)(Profile));
```

Here is the actions .js

```
export const fetchSportsFanDetails = () => ({
  type: FETCH_SPORTS_FAN_DETAILS_REQUEST
});
```

How does this work ?
Iam used to this way of

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        funds: state.funds
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getAllFunds: (options = {}) => {
             console.log('Inside dispatch');
            dispatch(getAllFunds(options));
        }
        ,  getAllFundsOnSearch: (options = {},data) => {
            dispatch(getAllFundsOnSearch(options,data));
        }

    };
}
```

and then calling this.props.getAllFiundsOnSearch().
Please note that we are using redux-saga .

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) and [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js#L16) :

> If you pass an object full of action creators instead of a function, connect will automatically call bindActionCreators for you internally. Each field of the mapDispatchToProps object is assumed to be an action creator